# Sumar Valores repetidos en php

Tags: php

Buen dia,

Tengo este array donde guardo incidente y cuanto tiempo en minutos sucedio:

`[["MAL ENTRENAMIENTO",60],["ELEVADOR",55],["AUTOESCANEO",245],["ZEBRA",60],["MRETROALIMENTACION",215],["ENTRENAMIENTO",59],["ELEVADOR",91],["MATERIAL EN SISTEMA",59],["NO ESCANEA TPM",60],["OTRO",60]]`

Y quisiera sumar los valores que esten repetidos , como es el caso de ELEVADOR, entonces seria algo como ELEVADOR : 2 y los minutos igual sumarlos, esto con el fin de graficar dicha informacion.

Agradeceria que alguien me puderia ayudar.

Comment: utiliza un array asociativo

Comment: Hola es muy importante agregar lo que trataste, revisa [ask] , saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

intenta esto muy simple.

```
<?php 
$array = [["MAL ENTRENAMIENTO",60],["ELEVADOR",55],["AUTOESCANEO",245],["ZEBRA",60],["MRETROALIMENTACION",215],["ENTRENAMIENTO",59],["ELEVADOR",91],["MATERIAL EN SISTEMA",59],["NO ESCANEA TPM",60],["OTRO",60]];
$array_assoc = [];
foreach($array as $i => $d){
    if(!isset($array_assoc[$d[0]])){
        $array_assoc[$d[0]] = array(
            'min' => $d[1],
            'ocu' => 1
        );
    }
    else {
        $array_assoc[$d[0]]['min'] += $d[1];
        $array_assoc[$d[0]]['ocu']++;
    }
}
print_r($array_assoc);
?>
```

el foreach va a recorrer todo el array y el la variable $d va a quedar la información de cada subarray ej:

```
 $d = ["ELEVADOR",60]
```

Con el primer if preguntamos si el valor que viene, para este caso el que se repite "ELEVADOR" ya existe en nuestra variable $array_assoc, si no existe lo creamos y le asignamos otro array, el dato min = minutos para sumarlos y el ocu para la cantidad de ocurrencias.

El "else" nos indica que ya existe el valor "ELEVADOR" y que si viene otro exactamente igual vamos a sumarle a min el valor $d[1], para este caso es 60 en el "if" y 91 en el "else".

observa que usamos $d[0] y $d[1];

```
$d = ["ELEVADOR",60]
$d[0] = "ELEVADOR";
$d[1] = 60;
```

Comment: muy amable, eso es lo que queria, gracias por la ayuda, se lo agradezco.

Comment: Con mucho gusto, para eso estamos.
Por favor califica la respuesta como "aceptada" para que otras personas no tengan que hacer una nueva pregunta similar.